# The type MiniProfiler exists in both Miniprofiler.Shared and MiniProfiler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, miniprofiler

I am trying to use the stack exchange `MiniProfiler` in my asp MVC project, but getting a really annoying error message in my view, where I am calling

```
@using StackExchange.Profiling
```

and

```
@MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()
```

on the `RenderIncludes` line, VS complains that

> The type 'MiniProfiler' exists in both 'MiniProfiler.Shared, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b44f9351044011a3' and 'MiniProfiler, Version=3.2.0.157, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b44f9351044011a3'

I already checked the (`.csprroj`) project file, and it only contains one element referencing `MiniProfiler`:

```
<Reference Include="MiniProfiler, Version=3.2.0.157, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b44f9351044011a3, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MiniProfiler.3.2.0.157\lib\net40\MiniProfiler.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I also checked in `packages.config` and it also only has 1 reference to `MiniProfiler`:

```
<package id="MiniProfiler" version="3.2.0.157" targetFramework="net452" />
```

I cleaned the project and restarted Visual Studio but with no success. What is happening here?

Comment: For anyone else finding this: it can also happen if you update MiniProfiler to v4 *but not all packages*. To resolve that, upgrade all packages to the same version.

Comment: This happened to me when I tried upgrading MiniProfiler to version 4, and then rolled back to version 3. `MiniProfiler.Shared` was still in the `/bin` folder. Thank!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I manageed to find the cause of this when I double-clicked on `MiniProfiler` under `References` in the solution explorer.

This opens up an object explorer in the main window, which was displaying some references which were **not visible** in the solution explorer (how annoying), including `MiniProfiler.Shared`.

So I checked the path for these, and they were in the `bin` folder. After physically deleting the files, my error went away.